# Logmein does not work at home?

Tags: remote-desktop, solidworks

I've been using logmein successfully for may situations and have had very good success.  Our company has an Log me in Pro account.  I have used this to share my desktop with customers.  At work, I have had no problem with my laptop.  At home, one program (solid-works) that I need to share with my customers, will not display the active screen.  I spent 45 min on the phone with both the software for the cad system and logmein support with not help.  I need help in narrowing down what the problem is on my computer.  The support guys at Solid-works got another remote software to work, so its not the program.  I can get the logmein to work at the office so its not the settings of the logmein pro account.  The LMI people say its a setting on my computer.?
-internet is fast enough at home
-can't narrow down the problem
-changed graphical settings and that didn't work.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and what had worked for me was making sure that in the LMI settings to make sure "Mirror Display" is unchecked.  This may also be called "Display Accelerator" depending on your version of LMI.  SolidWorks will be slow, but it not a program that's ever going to be fast via remote connection in my experience.

LMI (after logging in, before connecting to remote machine) > Preferences > Remote Control Settings > General.

FWIW we use the viewer rather than firing up the full SW app for speed.